# Nimbus Look And Feel JAVA - change global size of components

Tags: java, swing, size, global, nimbus

I was searching if there is possible to change global size of all components in Nimbus Look and Feel.

There is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) for re-sizing a component; but not for all components.

I've found something like this:
http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2007/12/nimbus-large-small-mini-components/

> November 6, 2008 at 11:29 am Sorry Matt there is no global setting for
>   size, that is again something we could think about adding as it seems
>   sensible.

but this post is from several years ago and maybe something has changed. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a nimbus specific way to achieve this.
[JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/) project has implementation to transform the whole UI to different scales- This can be applied to any look and feel.
You may want to check out [this demo](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.pbjar.org/blogs/jxlayer/version_2/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice, but if there isn't simple way to achieve that in nimbus (without using 3rd party libraries like JXLayer) - I have to look for other laf. Any (free for commercial use) recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());

  final SynthStyleFactory styleFactory = SynthLookAndFeel.getStyleFactory();
  SynthLookAndFeel.setStyleFactory(new SynthStyleFactory() {
    @Override
    public SynthStyle getStyle(JComponent c, Region id) {
      c.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
      return styleFactory.getStyle(c, id);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The below answer is an extension of the previous answer by @Stijn with the change being in the initialization approach as recommended in the doc. Quoting the links [nimbuslaf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) and [swing tutorials - size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html)

> ***Version Note***: Do not set the Nimbus look and feel explicitly by invoking the UIManager.setLookAndFeel method because not all versions
>   or implementations of Java SE 6 support Nimbus. Additionally, the
>   location of the Nimbus package changed between the JDK 6 Update 10 and
>   JDK 7 releases. Iterating through all installed look and feel
>   implementations is a more robust approach because if Nimbus is not
>   available, the default look and feel is used.

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        try {
            Constructor c = Class.forName("MyStyleFactory").getConstructor(String.class);
            c.newInstance("small"); // regular, mini, small or large
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError eiie){
        //
        } catch (LinkageError le){
        //
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        //
        }
        break;
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

File : MyStyleFactory.java

```
public class MyStyleFactory extends SynthStyleFactory {
    protected static String variant = "regular";

    final SynthStyleFactory styleFactory = SynthLookAndFeel.getStyleFactory();

    static {
        SynthLookAndFeel.setStyleFactory(new MyStyleFactory(variant));
    }

    public MyStyleFactory(String variant) {
        if (variant.equals("regular") || variant.equals("mini")
                || variant.equals("small") || variant.equals("large"))
            MyStyleFactory.variant = variant;
    }

    @Override
    public SynthStyle getStyle(JComponent c, Region id) {
        c.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", variant);
        return styleFactory.getStyle(c, id);
    }
}
```